# Rubber stuck on deployment to ec2 (sftp upload #<StringIO:0x000001029984c0> -> /tmp/setup_remote_aliases)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, amazon-ec2, capistrano, ec2-ami

I am using rubber (built on top of capistrano) to deploy to my ec2 instance. I basically followed the rail cast from Ryan bates http://railscasts.com/episodes/347-rubber-and-amazon-ec2?view=comments. In that rail cast he did not list the ami but the config did require me to list the ami so I did. Here is a link to my config.

http://www.text-upload.com/read,4081177118013

I have tried different ami's as well. I have also checked each stackoverflow questions and but there are no answers. rubber connects and I can check in aws console the instance is launched but it gets stuck on that line.

I tried cap rubber:bootstrap. i also tried cap rubber:destroy_all and then cap rubber:create_staging

Here is what it gets stuck at.

```
  * executing `rubber:create_staging'
Hostname to use for staging instance [production]: 
Roles to use for staging instance [apache,app,collectd,common,db:primary=true,elasticsearch,examples,graphite_server,graphite_web,graylog_elasticsearch,graylog_mongodb,graylog_server,graylog_web,haproxy,mongodb,monit,passenger,postgresql,postgresql_master,web,web_tools]: 
  * executing `rubber:create'
  * Security Group already in cloud, syncing rules: rubbertest_production_examples
  * Security Group already in cloud, syncing rules: rubbertest_production_haproxy
  * Security Group already in cloud, syncing rules: rubbertest_production_web
  * Security Group already in cloud, syncing rules: rubbertest_production_monit
  * Security Group already in cloud, syncing rules: rubbertest_production_graylog_elasticsearch
  * Security Group already in cloud, syncing rules: rubbertest_production_mongodb
  * Security Group already in cloud, syncing rules: rubbertest_production_db
  * Security Group already in cloud, syncing rules: rubbertest_production_web_tools
  * Security Group already in cloud, syncing rules: rubbertest_production_collectd
  * Security Group already in cloud, syncing rules: rubbertest_production_common
  * Security Group already in cloud, syncing rules: rubbertest_production_production
  * Security Group already in cloud, syncing rules: rubbertest_production_default
  * Security Group already in cloud, syncing rules: rubbertest_production_postgresql
  * Security Group already in cloud, syncing rules: rubbertest_production_graylog_server
  * Security Group already in cloud, syncing rules: rubbertest_production_elasticsearch
  * Security Group already in cloud, syncing rules: rubbertest_production_passenger
  * Security Group already in cloud, syncing rules: rubbertest_production_graphite_server
  * Security Group already in cloud, syncing rules: rubbertest_production_graylog_web
  * Security Group already in cloud, syncing rules: rubbertest_production_graylog_mongodb
  * Security Group already in cloud, syncing rules: rubbertest_production_graphite_web
  * Security Group already in cloud, syncing rules: rubbertest_production_apache
  * Security Group already in cloud, syncing rules: rubbertest_production_postgresql_master
  * Security Group already in cloud, syncing rules: rubbertest_production_app
 ** Creating instance ami-eafa77da/m1.small/rubbertest_production_default,rubbertest_production_web,rubbertest_production_web_tools,rubbertest_production_production,rubbertest_production_apache,rubbertest_production_app,rubbertest_production_passenger,rubbertest_production_collectd,rubbertest_production_common,rubbertest_production_monit,rubbertest_production_db,rubbertest_production_postgresql,rubbertest_production_postgresql_master,rubbertest_production_elasticsearch,rubbertest_production_examples,rubbertest_production_graphite_server,rubbertest_production_graphite_web,rubbertest_production_graylog_elasticsearch,rubbertest_production_graylog_mongodb,rubbertest_production_mongodb,rubbertest_production_graylog_server,rubbertest_production_graylog_web,rubbertest_production_haproxy/Default
 ** Instance production created: i-eb8717d8
Waiting for instances to start...........................................
 ** Instance running, fetching hostname/ip data
  * executing `rubber:_allow_root_ssh'
  * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: '  bash -l -c 'cp /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys /root/.ssh/'"
    servers: ["50.112.28.254"]
. ** Failed to connect to 50.112.28.254, retrying
  * executing `rubber:_allow_root_ssh'
  * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: '  bash -l -c 'cp /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys /root/.ssh/'"
    servers: ["50.112.28.254"]
.............. ** timeout in initial connect, retrying
  * executing `rubber:_allow_root_ssh'
  * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: '  bash -l -c 'cp /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys /root/.ssh/'"
    servers: ["50.112.28.254"]
. ** Can't connect as user ubuntu to 50.112.28.254, assuming root allowed
  * executing `rubber:_direct_connection_50.112.28.254_864'
  * executing "echo"
    servers: ["50.112.28.254"]
..    [50.112.28.254] executing command
 ** [out :: 50.112.28.254] Please login as the bitnami user rather than root user.
 ** [out :: 50.112.28.254] 
.....    command finished in 14009ms
  * executing `rubber:setup_static_ips'
  * executing `rubber:setup_local_aliases'
 ** Writing out aliases into local machines /etc/hosts, sudo access needed
Password:
 ** Auto role: apache => production.foo.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
 ** Auto role: app => production.foo.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
 ** Auto role: passenger => production.foo.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
 ** Auto role: collectd => production.foo.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
 ** Auto role: common => production.foo.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
 ** Auto role: monit => production.foo.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
 ** Auto role: db => production.foo.com, {:primary=>true, :platform=>"linux"}
 ** Auto role: postgresql => production.foo.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
 ** Auto role: postgresql_master => production.foo.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
 ** Auto role: elasticsearch => production.foo.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
 ** Auto role: examples => production.foo.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
 ** Auto role: graphite_server => production.foo.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
 ** Auto role: graphite_web => production.foo.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
 ** Auto role: graylog_elasticsearch => production.foo.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
 ** Auto role: graylog_mongodb => production.foo.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
 ** Auto role: mongodb => production.foo.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
 ** Auto role: graylog_server => production.foo.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
 ** Auto role: graylog_web => production.foo.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
 ** Auto role: haproxy => production.foo.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
 ** Auto role: web => production.foo.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
 ** Auto role: web_tools => production.foo.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
  * executing `rubber:setup_remote_aliases'
    servers: ["production.foo.com"]
 ** sftp upload #<StringIO:0x000001029984c0> -> /tmp/setup_remote_aliases
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a 64-bit instance-store Ubuntu 12.04 LTS image. the ami varies by region, go to http://alestic.com/ to locate the image-id for your preferred region. (on the right hand side)